# Updating app content online alternatives (ListView rows etc.)

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, authentication, parse-platform

How do the famous apps as SoundCloud or apps, that update their content often store or update their data?  I know Parse.com but how do the bigger apps solve this?

I mean updating for example ListView content (adding rows continuosly and so on...)
And what would you suggest me, if i'm developing app, where do I need to:

- add rows in a ListView (for example one row a day, and on click view some more info)
- support login/signup via facebook (or twitter or email)
- sending push notifications, etc..
- Do some "check" to my database if someone clicks on a button (who "checked" - name,...->                                                                 ...                                                                                login info)

Thanks a a lot for reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse.com is a company run by Facebook its a complete Backend Solution for mobile , other alternative is Urban airship , as for as your query goes , add one row a day in a listview , the code is written in your app and you query from Parse's backend database and then display it to the user of your app via methods connected to update a listview.

parse is Facebook so ParseFacebookUtlis has a method to login a user and get a acess token for your app to acess what ever data u wish to use with a social network site such as Facebook 
similarly email or twitter can be involved into the app user management system.
You can track all your analytics as to who opened your app or who logged in and also who click'd a push notifications.

For more info: check this - https://www.parse.com/tutorials

I would be happy to help further if needed